# Eclipse Java Servlet access to higher level directory

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

I've installed Eclipse with web development and during download have installed Tomcat7 to dir E:\Eclipse\tomcat7.

When in Eclipse and trying to test the program I'm getting a realPath of

*C:/Users/user/Documents/eclipseJEEWorkspace/javaWebPages/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/org.example.web/WEB-INF/classes/*

as my real path and not what I expect which is *E:\Eclipse\tomcat7\webapps\org.example.web/WEB-INF/classes/*

1) how do I get the real path of the servlet rather than the temporary path...

or am I missing something with how Eclipse uses the installed server?  If this is the way then do I have to continuously create the WAR and fiddle around recreating/deleting all the time?

The reason for this is I'm also trying to get a JAVA Servlet getting access to a file in a path higher than webapps.  I'm new to servlets....

My development includes third party software that all reference an individual file **our.properties** so changing the structure is unfortunately not a option.

My directory structure is:

```
/tomcat
   /mycompany
      /properties
         our.properties //the file we want to access
         /*otherfiles
      /html
         /*not used in this context but to show usage
      /javascript
         /*not used in this context but to show usage
   /webapps
      /org.example01.web
          /META-INF
          /WEB-INF
      /org.example02.web  
          /META-INF
          /WEB-INF
      /org.example03.web
          /META-INF
          /WEB-INF
```

How do I tell my Servlet to access the our.properties file?

I've tried getPath, getResource but without getting the first bit to work, I doubt I'll be getting anywhere fast.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run Tomcat under Eclipse, via the Tomcat plugin, the webapps path is changed. Eclipse uses `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/` folder to deploy the project. That's not a temporary path, it's the actual path since your web application is deployed there. 
If you run tomcat from command line, or as a service and deploy your web application, you'll see that the path of the servlet will be as you expected.
In order the change the default path to deploy for Eclipse, double click to your Tomcat under Servers view and modify Server locations section. 
[image: Eclipse Tomcat path settings]